# Insert last row in a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables

I have a temp table that spits out bunch of rows as below:

Temp table structure:

```
create table #final(rownum int,_CID int,Output nvarchar(max))
insert into #final
select rownum,_CID ,Output  from ...and goes the sproc
```

Final select:

```
declare @num_records int =  @@ROWCOUNT
if @num_records > 0
select Output from #final
```

So the Output is:

```
12345abc  65432  TEST1  2383 JOHN  KIARA     N   987456321456 
12345abc  65432  TEST2  3570 JANE  lastname  A   989746532366 
12345abc  65432  TEST3  3573 KANE  AMBER     N   987454121445
```

Requirement: I want to add a last row to the output that shows count of records above.

Desired output:

```
12345abc  65432  TEST1  2383 JOHN  KIARA     N   987456321456 
12345abc  65432  TEST2  3570 JANE  lastname  A   989746532366 
12345abc  65432  TEST3  3573 KANE  AMBER     N   987454121445
TRAILER   3
```

Is there a way to do this? I will add a rextester link soon. Any Help?!

Comment: Not really.  All rows in a table have the same set of columns, and you are suggesting that the last row has a different set from the rest.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If my understanding from what you ask is right, yes. The last row will look different from the rest of the rows. It will only have the test 'TRAILER' and the count of above records

Comment: Add `NULL`s using `UNION`

Comment: And I didn't even mention that tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no such thing as a "last row".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree with you, there is no order so there is no _last row_, but from what I understand the OP need to add this row to the rows returned, which make `UNION` a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` after you select the rows, which will add the row to the end of result set returned by the `SELECT` statement *Not after the last row* because there is no order which make there is no *last row*:

```
SELECT *
FROM #final
UNION
SELECT
'TRAILER',   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #final), NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL;
```

Result:

```
+----------+-------+-------+------+------+----------+------+--------------+
|   Col1   | Col2  | Col3  | Col4 | Col5 |   Col6   | Col7 |     Col8     |
+----------+-------+-------+------+------+----------+------+--------------+
| 12345abc | 65432 | TEST1 | 2383 | JOHN | KIARA    | N    | 987456321456 |
| 12345abc | 65432 | TEST2 | 3570 | JANE | lastname | A    | 989746532366 |
| 12345abc | 65432 | TEST3 | 3573 | KANE | AMBER    | N    | 987454121445 |
| TRAILER  |     3 | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL     | NULL | NULL         |
+----------+-------+-------+------+------+----------+------+--------------+
```

Comment: @sami I have modified script to generate count dynamically.. also we could maintain a separate column as order by and then set the value to count(*)+1 to denote it is the last column..or depending on the final usage we could order by nulls last(assuming that column does not has nulls)

Comment: How do you calculate the number of rows?